# Prove If Statement Is Valid or Invalid

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Given:

Every student has an email account
Maggie does not have an email account
Homer is a student
Using E(x): x has an email, S(x): x is a student and M to represent Maggie while H represents Homer, I came up with the following premises:

- 1: ∀x[S(x)→E(x)]
- 2: ¬E(M)
- 3: S(H)

I then have to determine if the two following conclusions are valid. The first conclusion:

Maggie is not a student
I determined this not a valid conclusion because you can only reach it by using the 'denying the antecedent' fallacy.

Is my thinking correct?

Thanks

Comment: What's deny the antecedent fallacy.  If Maggie is a student she'd have an email account.  But she doesn't.  So it's impossible for her to be a student.  Seems a valid conclusion to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It would be 'denying the *consequent*' (in order to get the denial of the antecedent) .. better known as Modus Tollens... which is perfectly valid.

To be precise, from the universal you can instantitate Maggie:

$S(M) \to E(M)$

This, combined with $\neg E(M)$ gives you $\neg S(M)$ by Modus Tollens

Answer (score 1):

I think it is not "denying the antecedent" but we can conclude by using contraposition. We know that $\forall x[S(x) \implies E(x)]$ and we are given $\lnot E(M)$ and implication of $\lnot E(M)$ is given as $\lnot S(M)$ (not the other way around), therefore conclusion is $\lnot E(M) \implies \lnot S(M)$. From the first premise, we know that $S(M) \implies E(M)$ is valid. Therefore, contrapositive $\lnot E(M) \implies \lnot S(M)$ should also be valid.

If we were given "Maggie is not a student" and conclusion was "Maggie does not have an e-mail account", then it would be denying the antecedent.